# Trying to fetch JSON data and put it to googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have problem with value setting in googlesheet. Googlesheet setValue support only array but i need to put object in rows.

I tried use appendRow but it won't work in custom functions. I also tried setValue with converting my objects to array but then i missed some data.

This is my fetching function. It works and gets all data i need but it's really hard for me to place it into googlesheet.

```
function importTrelloJSON(url){
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(content);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


  var trelloJSON = data.map(function(el, index) {
      var customFieldItems = el.customFieldItems.map(function(el){
        return [el.idCustomField, el.value.number];
      });

     return  { name: el.name, customFieldItems: customFieldItems };
   });

  retrun trelloJSON;
}


and this is my JSON structure, sometimes there is nested data


[
{
"id": "5ce26ef1d5bdac4ec20e8982",
"name": "WWW",
"customFieldItems": []
},
{
"id": "5ced04d96ec7ed6120b5e91d",
"name": "Marketing",
"customFieldItems": []
},
{
"id": "5cfed3d8e88f931008aa58ad",
"name": "Reset softu Android",
"customFieldItems": [
{
"id": "5cfed4145d019516555a9086",
"value": {
"number": "100"
},
"idCustomField": "5ced79c27bbd7102945ba1ff",
"idModel": "5cfed3d8e88f931008aa58ad",
"modelType": "card"
}
]
},
```

I tried using ready importJSON function https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON but it's not working with my queries.

Thanks for help.

//edit
Now i can display data but when i push to array i have problem with range. The number of data columns does not match the number of columns in the range.
I tried Math.max.apply(Math, trelloJSON.map(function (el) { return el.length })). But it's not working anymore.

Here is my new code:

```
function importTrelloJSON(url){
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(content);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var mainArray = new Array();


  var trelloJSON = data.map(function(el, index) {
    mainArray = [];
    mainArray.push(el.name);

   el.customFieldItems.map(function(el){
        mainArray.push(el.idCustomField);
        mainArray.push(el.value.number);  
      });

    Logger.log(mainArray);

    return mainArray;
   });

  sheet.getRange(1,1, trelloJSON.length, Math.max.apply(Math, trelloJSON.map(function (el) { return el.length }))).setValues(trelloJSON);

}
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you want? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm your situation and think of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So here is original JSON file: https://www.codepile.net/pile/b3r9VxkR. And I wrote this function to get values that I need to put in google sheets:  https://www.codepile.net/pile/kjMm6Mjb As you can see I take only name and customFieldItems as array of arrays. All is returned as object. And now somehow I need to put this data in googlesheet. Only this name and all from customFieldItems array. Here is final JSON after importTrelloJSON function: https://www.codepile.net/pile/e1NnR81l . This JSON I want to put in googlesheet.

Comment: Now final JSON looks like this: https://www.codepile.net/pile/ejOaPVn5

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you where the input and output you want are?

Comment: Input is just JSON and i want to put it all in googlesheet. I want every value in array to be a diffrent column.

Comment: Awww I thought I have to use setValue but actually I can just return this trelloJSON array and it works daaamn. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.